# How Do I reduce lag in my first game? Python

Tags: python, lag

I am a beginner to code but I wanted to make my own game with no inspiration from other already made games. I know the basics of python and have been familiar with it for some months now. The game that I'm currently working on is not even close to done. I just am wondering why am I lagging so much after I made a blinking door? You can roast my code if you want, I just need help for this and have not fond anything that would help my problem. I am also new to Stack Overflow

code:

```
import turtle, os, time
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("The Last Fortresses")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=1000, height=1000)

health_h = 100
health_e = 100
c = 1

door = turtle.Turtle()
door.speed(0)
door.shape("square")
door.color("orange")
door.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
door.penup()
door.goto(470, -40)

Fortress = turtle.Turtle()
Fortress.speed(0)
Fortress.shape("square")
Fortress.color("grey")
Fortress.shapesize(stretch_wid=100000, stretch_len=1)
Fortress.penup()
Fortress.right(90)
Fortress.forward(100)
Fortress.goto(-400, -100)

Fortressr = turtle.Turtle()
Fortressr.speed(0)
Fortressr.shape("square")
Fortressr.color("grey")
Fortressr.shapesize(stretch_wid=100000, stretch_len=1)
Fortressr.penup()
Fortressr.right(90)
Fortressr.forward(100)
Fortressr.goto(-400, 150)

Fortressw = turtle.Turtle()
Fortressw.speed(0)
Fortressw.shape("square")
Fortressw.color("silver")
Fortressw.shapesize(stretch_wid=10000000, stretch_len=12)
Fortressw.penup()
Fortressw.right(90)
Fortressw.forward(100)
Fortressw.goto(-400, 25)

hero = turtle.Turtle()
hero.speed(0)
hero.shape("square")
hero.color("blue")
hero.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
hero.penup()
hero.goto(-450, -40)

ok = 0

playerspeed = 15

def hero_jump():
    ok = 1
    hero.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=5)
    hero.left(90)
    hero.forward(50)
    time.sleep(.5)
    hero.backward(50)
    hero.right(90)
    hero.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    ok = 0

def hero_right():
    if ok == 0:
        hero.forward(15)
    
def hero_left(): 
    if ok == 0:
        hero.right(180)
        hero.forward(15)
        hero.right(180)
    
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(hero_right, "w")
wn.onkeypress(hero_left, "s")
wn.onkeypress(hero_jump, "j")

while c > 0:
    c = 0
    door.color("blue")
    time.sleep(1)
    door.color("orange") ## - right here is making lag - ##
    time.sleep(1)
    c = 1


def is_collided_with(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 10 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 10 ## - not finished part - ##
```

Answer (score 1):

The game is lagging because you are pausing the game with `sleep`:

```
while c > 0:
    c = 0
    door.color("blue")
    time.sleep(1)  # pause game 1 second
    door.color("orange") ## - right here is making lag - ##
    time.sleep(1) # pause game 1 second
    c = 1
```

While the loop is sleeping the entire game freezes. To flash the door, you should use a timer.

Comment: if you run it without sleep, it doesn't actually go faster

Comment: oh thanks, guys, stack overflow is better than I expected